# getResource() method with maven

Tags: java, maven

I have two projects. One Java application without Maven and other with Maven.

Can anyone explain me why in the first project (without Maven), the following code works, while in the second one it gives me a NullPointerException? Both have the same name and package structure.

```
protected static Image createIcon(String path, String desc) {
    URL imageUrl = Prueba.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
    return (new ImageIcon(imageUrl, desc).getImage());

}
```

path value is "co/com/claro/testicon/images/Logo16x16.png"

Comment: Is the png file in `src/main/resources`? It should be.

Comment: Hello @dan1st. No, it doesn't. I have all images in a java package. If you say it should be in the resources folder, why must be and how i have to change my code in order to load my icon?

Comment: Because the source folder is for sources (.java files). The resources directory is for resources like images.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have moved my icon to the resources folder, changed the path and it worked.

Comment: It does not explain why it is not working though, it technically should work unless the resource file is being filtered out by Maven when it is in the java sources. I don't think that is standard behavior though. Ultimately there is only one classpath so it shouldn't matter where you put the file; it is only cleaner to put resource files in the resources folder and you gain access to the resources plugin's features that way.

Comment: That's right. It worked for me but i would like to know why this behaviour.

Comment: @Gimby The source folder isn't used at runtime, it is only used for compile information. When Maven assembles a jar, it copies the class files it generated and anything in the resources folder in to the final assembly.

Answer (score 0):

As @dan1st mentioned in a comment:

> Because the source folder is for sources (.java files). The resources directory is for resources like images.

I have moved my icon to the resources folder, changed the path and it worked.